# How to update a model with jena API and SPARQL, eg. update value of a node and all its associated triples

Tags: java, model, sparql, jena

I need to replace an instance by another one in the whole ontology and not just at one place.

this is my query: 
 ----sparql jena
String rename = PREFIX ns: http://www.semanticweb.org/ontothese#

```
        PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> 

            delete { ns:x rdf:type  ?label}

            insert { ns:yrdf:type  ?label}

            where {ns:xrdf:type  ?label};

UpdateAction.parseExecute( rename, model );
```

---

but the execution of this query replace x with y.

Thanks

Comment: which means you have to replace all triples in which the instance occurs - that's it. SPARQL Update is the way to go here

Comment: even with seeing your query now, it's unclear what you want and what does not work. Yes, your query just replaces `x` by `y` but only for the `rdf:type` triples. Any other triple indeed not.

Comment: `delete { ns:x ?p ?o}

            insert { ns:y ?p ?o}

            where {ns:x ?p ?o}` - this query would replace all occurrences of `x` in subject position. Indeed, for object position you have to extend the query by using `UNION` operator

Comment: @UninformedUser: ah yes i understand thank you. could you give me an example with union operator please. ?

Comment: @UninformedUser: is this correct please?

 delete { ns:x ?o ?p}     insert { ns:y?o ?p} where {ns:x ?o ?p} union {
        delete { ?s ?o ns:x} insert { ?s ?o ns:y} where {?s ?o ns:x}};

Comment: no, that does not work. It should be `delete { ns:x ?p ?o . ?s ?p1 ns:x } insert { ns:y ?p ?o . ?s ?p1 ns:y } where { { ns:x ?p ?o } UNION { ?s ?p1 ?nx:x } }` I guess - you have to test whether it works

Comment: thank you, i test it. it add y but x still exist. 

                           ---- 
  String rename = "PREFIX ns: <http://www.semanticweb.org/ontothese#>" + 
   "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> "+
                "delete { ns:x ?p ?o . ?s ?p1 ns:x.}" +
                "insert { ns:y ?p ?o  . ?s ?p1 ns:y. }" +
                "where {{ns:x ?p ?o} UNION {?s ?p1 ns:x.}}"
                        -----------

Comment: I think the "Delete" is ignored when I put it with the Insert. However, when I run it individually, it works!

Comment: Others persons who can help me please .?

Comment: can't reproduce your problem, works for me as expected with `delete { ns:x ?p ?o . ?s ?p1 ns:x }
insert { ns:y ?p ?o . ?s ?p1 ns:y }
where { { ns:x ?p ?o } UNION { ?s ?p1 ns:x } }`

Comment: @UninformedUser Thank you for help. But i don't why this don't work for me. 
String rename = "" + "prefix ns: <http://www.semanticweb.org/ontothese#>" +"PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> "+ "delete { ns:hanane ?p ?o . ?s ?p1 ns:hanane } insert { ns:mina ?p ?o . ?s ?p1 ns:mina } where { { ns:hanane ?p ?o } UNION { ?s ?p1 ns:hanane } }"; UpdateAction.parseExecute( rename, model );----but when i excute this querry to verify. i give this result. it add mina but dont delete hanane. SELECT ?mere WHERE { ?mere rdf:type ns:Humain.} |mere |=| ns:mina   || ns:ayden|| ns:hanane |

Comment: @Joshua Taylor could you help me please?

Comment: please provide sample data (in Turtle or N-Triples syntax) + sample Java code + sample SPARQL query - and please **edit your question** and add it there, don't put it into the comments